# use a variable for table name in mysql sproc

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, query-string

I'm trying to pass a table name into my mysql stored procedure to use this sproc to select off of different tables but it's not working...

this is what I"m trying:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `usp_SelectFromTables`(
 IN TableName varchar(100)
)
BEGIN
        SELECT * FROM @TableName;
END
```

I've also tried it w/o the @ sign and that just tells me that TableName doesn't exist...which I know :)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It depends on the DBMS, but the notation usually requires Dynamic SQL, and runs into the problem that the return values from the function depend on the inputs when it is executed.  This gives the system conniptions.  As a general rule (and therefore probably subject to exceptions), DBMS do not allow you to use placeholders (parameters) for structural elements of a query such as table names or column names; they only allow you to specify values such as column values.

Some DBMS do have stored procedure support that will allow you to build up an SQL string and then work with that, using 'prepare' or 'execute immediate' or similar operations.  Note, however, that you are suddenly vulnerable to SQL injection attacks - someone who can execute your procedure is then able to control, in part, what SQL gets executed.

Comment: ( IN YOURVARNAME DATATYPE ) I prefer to use IN/OUT so that I can provide a dynamic variable, and not just hard code a static one into the stored procedure. But in before someone suggests validation, because you should ALWAYS Validate, Forms side AND Server side just to make sure, but anyways.

Answer (score 71):

```
SET @cname:='jello';
SET @vname:='dwb';
SET @sql_text = concat('select concept_id,concept_name,',@vname,' from enc2.concept a JOIN enc2.ratings b USING(concept_id) where concept_name like (''%',@cname,'%'') and 3 is not null order by 3 asc');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql_text;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Comment: WOW, what a brilliant way!

Comment: How is this answering the question? The OP asks How to pass a table name as variable into a stored procedure!!!

Comment: @ifedi: that's right. so I suppose the CONCAT function should include a variable name passed using the (IN tableName) statement...

Comment: Also, remember that in a Stored Procedure, you don't have to use `@varname:='XXX'` and `@varname` for reading them, but simply `DECLARE` them, then `SET varname=value`, and `SELECT value`...

Answer (score 19):

An extra bit that caused me problems.

I wanted to set the table name and field dynamically in a query as @kyle asked, but I also wanted to store the result of that query into a variable `@a` within the query.

Instead of putting the variable `@a` into the `concat` literally, you need to include it as part of the string text.

```
delimiter //

CREATE PROCEDURE removeProcessed(table_name VARCHAR(255), keyField VARCHAR(255), maxId INT, num_rows INT)

BEGIN
  SET @table_name = table_name;
  SET @keyField = keyField;
  SET @maxId = maxId;
  SET @num_rows = num_rows;

  SET @sql_text1 = concat('SELECT MIN(',@keyField,') INTO @a FROM ',@table_name);
  PREPARE stmt1 FROM @sql_text1;
  EXECUTE stmt1;
  DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt1;

  loop_label:  LOOP
    SET @sql_text2 = concat('SELECT ',@keyField,' INTO @z FROM ',@table_name,' WHERE ',@keyField,' >= ',@a,' ORDER BY ',@keyField,' LIMIT ',@num_rows,',1');
    PREPARE stmt2 FROM @sql_text2;
    EXECUTE stmt2;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt2;

    ...Additional looping code...

    END LOOP;
END
//

delimiter ;
```

So in `@sql_text1` assign the result of the query to `@a` within the string using:

`') INTO @a FROM '`

Then in `@sql_text2` use `@a` as an actual variable:

`,' WHERE ',@keyField,' >= ',`@a`,' ORDER BY '`