# Calling column name in stored procedure

Tags: mysql

As stored procedures go this should be fairly easy but its not turning out that way. Two inputs: cname (concept name, concept table) and vname (variable or column name, ratings table). The cname input works well but when I input the vname all I get back is the input text.

So if I "call enc2.sptest('jello','dwb');" I'll get back everything with the word 'jello' (cname) in it but I won't get back the value in the column 'dwb' (vname). Can MySQL accept column name inputs? Are there work-arounds?

```
drop procedure if exists enc2.sptest;
delimiter $$
create procedure enc2.sptest (in cname varchar(1000),in vname text)
begin
select
a.concept_id
,a.concept_name
,b.vname 
from enc2.concept a,enc2.ratings b
where a.concept_name like concat('%',cname,'%')
and vname is not null
and a.concept_id=b.concept_id
order by vname asc;
end
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [use a variable for table name in mysql sproc](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2754423/use-a-variable-for-table-name-in-mysql-sproc)

Comment: Thanks for the link Michael, worked it out.

Answer (score 0):

In case anybody is wondering of the answer, I believe you will need to manually create the query and execute it from a prepared statement as shown below.

```
drop procedure if exists enc2.sptest;
delimiter $$
create procedure enc2.sptest (in cname varchar(1000),in vname text)
begin
    set @query = CONCAT(' ',
    ' select ',
    ' a.concept_id ',
    ' ,a.concept_name ',
    ' ,b.`' , vname , '`  ',
    ' from concept a,ratings b ',
    ' where a.concept_name like ? ',
    ' and `', vname , '` is not null ',
    ' and a.concept_id=b.concept_id ',
    ' order by `', vname, '` asc; ',
    ' ');
    -- select @query;
    set @cname = concat('%',cname,'%');
    prepare statement from @query;
    execute statement using @cname;
    deallocate prepare statement;
end
$$
```

There are things to be worried about when doing this, such as SQL injection attacks and column names with spaces.

- SQL injection attacks can be prevented if you use parameters in the SQL query (indicated by the "?" in the statement with the value being provided by parameters when executing the statement).
- Field names with spaces can be handled using backticks `