# For statement in Firebird to Loop statement in Mysql

Tags: mysql, firebird

I have this SQL code in firebird and works very well

```
set term !! ;

EXECUTE BLOCK AS
declare variable vtable_name VARCHAR(31);
BEGIN
for select table_name from mytables into :vtable_name
execute statement 'DROP TABLE ' || :vtable_name || ';';
END!!

set term ; !!
```

Now I'm trying to do one very similar in Mysql database. Reading mysql manual I read about LOOP satement and about WHILE statement.

This my mysql code, but don't works

```
WHILE (SET @vtable_name  = (select table_name from mytables))
DO
  BEGIN
   DROP TABLE @vtable_name;
  END;
END WHILE;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that "(select table_name from mytables)" statment will return a result set and you assign an entire result set to a variable. 
Second issue is that DROP / SELECT statement will not allow dynamic table name / column names.

You can use dynamic sql, see demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cf278/1

and [use a variable for table name in mysql sproc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2754423/use-a-variable-for-table-name-in-mysql-sproc)