# MySQL Table Template w/ FUNCTION/PROCEDURE

Tags: mysql, sql

I am creating several logbooks on the same site—all with the same structure, so when I need to add a new logbook, I'd like to be able to do so with a simple function or something (since the table-structure will be exactly the same.)

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE FUNCTION GenerateNewLogbook(LogbookTitle varchar(15))
    BEGIN
        DROP TABLE IF EXISTS LogbookTitle;
        CREATE TABLE LogBookTitle (
          time timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT NOW(),
          username varchar(25) DEFAULT NULL,
          message text,
          crossout tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
          post_id mediumint(9) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
          file_id text,
          PRIMARY KEY (post_id)
        ) ENGINE=InnoDb AUTO_INCREMENT=0 DEFAULT CHARACTER SET=latin1;
    END//

DELIMITER ;
```

The error I'm getting is:

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'BEGIN
>           DROP TABLE IF EXISTS LogbookTitle;
>           CREATE TABLE LogBookTit' at line 2

I've tried many things: Replacing the ";" with "//", creating a PROCEDURE instead of a FUNCTION, adding "@" before LogBookTitle, removing BEGIN/END, etc. and have spent quite a while searching for examples to no avail.

What's wrong with the above code?

Comment: Your question is **very** similar to [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2754423/use-a-variable-for-table-name-in-mysql-sproc).  Therefore, I am going to mark it as a duplicate of that.  In short, you need to [PREPARE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/prepare.html) a statement and [EXECUTE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/execute.html) it.

Comment: @Buggabill I don't think the two are the same. Although I *am* trying to create a table whose name is variable, if I change "LogbookTitle" to something else (something non-variable) only within the BEGIN/END block (so LogBookTitle isn't used), I get the same error; that is, it doesn't look like my problem is the variable at all.