# Get list of schemas and then use that list to select tables

Tags: mysql

I am trying to get a unique list of all of the values from a specific table in in MySQL where the schema name matches a pattern.

For example I want to combing this into one query if possible
"SELECT SCHEMA_NAME FROM information_schema.SCHEMATA where SCHEMA_NAME like "Database_ID%";

"SELECT `table1`.`field` from Database_ID01"

"SELECT `table1`.`field` from Database_ID02"

...

Is this something that is possible using MySQL only?

Answer (score 0):

```
 SELECT table1.field from Database_ID01
 UNION
 SELECT table1.field from Database_ID02
```

Or, if you want to be sure to have no duplicates:

```
 SELECT DISTICNT fieldname FROM
 ( SELECT table1.field as fieldname from Database_ID01
   UNION
   SELECT table1.field as fieldname from Database_ID02
 )
```

Comment: But is it possible to have it take the list from the first query and use that?

Comment: Simple: No. Actual MySQL-Tables cant be referenced (eg. as variable). They have to be constant. You can build the query outside MySQL...

Comment: Oh, there might be a solution. Look at the second reply to [that](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2754423/use-a-variable-for-table-name-in-mysql-sproc) question.