# Get the returned value from a prepared statement MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures, prepared-statement

I was trying to make a stored procedure where I want to get a random value on the database where the table name and other conditions of my query are dynamic (in stored proc params).

```
    DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `myproc`;

DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE `myproc`(IN `tablename` VARCHAR(50), IN `isShow` TINYINT(1), IN `isAdd` TINYINT(1))
BEGIN
    SET @tname := tablename;
    SET @isshow := isShow;
    SET @isAdd := isAdd;
    SET @pcode := '';

    SET @s = CONCAT('SELECT t.pcode
        FROM ', @tname, ' AS t 
        JOIN (SELECT ROUND(RAND() * (SELECT MAX(idx) FROM ', @tname,' )) AS id) AS x 
        WHERE 
            t.idx >= x.id AND 
            t.isShow = ', @isshow,' AND
            t.isAdd = ', @isAdd,
        ' LIMIT 1');

    checkhand: WHILE (!@pcode) DO
        PREPARE sp_query FROM @s; 
        EXECUTE sp_query; 
        DEALLOCATE PREPARE sp_query;

        LEAVE checkhand;
    END WHILE ;
END //
DELIMITER ;
```

Since I use @var as tablename, I referred to this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2754423/use-a-variable-for-table-name-in-mysql-sproc) and create my SQL query in `CONCAT` then run it as `Stored Procedure`. Right now, my tables has holes so what I did was to do a `WHILE` loop until  get a record with **pcode** value.

My problem was, it is still returning blank pcode which means my @pcode var doesnt get the return value of query. Honestly I don't have idea how to store the result of my query ran in prepared statement to a variable and return it as result of my stored procedure.

Any help will do. Please correct me. Not pro sql user. Thanks

My while loop supposed to do like this:

```
while (!t.pcode) {
    // do query and check if i get t.pcode
    return t.pcode
}
```

Comment: You're using PHP, so why do you care about the 'holes'?

Comment: im trying to do it all by mysql alone

Comment: have you excecuted the query with dummy values in your database engine?

Comment: yes sir, it is working. the problem is sometimes it returns 0 row because of the hole

Comment: and im sure that my WHILE doesnt do what it needs to do

Comment: Try: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ea0fb/1).