# inserting data into more tables at once based on the cells from another table

Tags: php, mysql

I am inserting the data into 2 tables.

```
$query1="INSERT INTO business (id) VALUES ('$id')";
$result1=mysql_query($query1);

$query2="INSERT INTO premier (id) VALUES ('$id')";
$result2=mysql_query($query2);
```

I have a third table ( table_list ) in which these 2 tables (business, premier ) are listed. How can I use this third table ( table_list ) in order to insert the data into these tables without having to use 2 queries.

Thanks

Comment: don't use mysql. It's deprecated! Use mysqli (or PDO) for PHP SQL operations!

Comment: anyway I need to get some clue how to do it

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2754423/use-a-variable-for-table-name-in-mysql-sproc. (summary: it's not meant to be easy or possible to use one table's contents to get other table names.)