# Syntax for using @var for table prefix in MySQL query

Tags: mysql, prefix

I'd like to use a `@var` to store a table prefix like:

```
SET @prefix = 'wp_';
```

To create the table names `wp_users` (`wp_` plus `users`) and `wp_usermeta` in my query below:

```
SET @username   = 'username'; 
SET @password   = 'P@55W0rd';
SET @email  = 'em@il.com';

INSERT INTO `wp_users` (`ID`, `user_login`, `user_pass`, `user_nicename`, `user_email`, `user_url`, `user_registered`, `user_activation_key`, `user_status`, `display_name`) 
VALUES 
(NULL , @username, MD5(@password), '', @email, '', NOW(), '', '0', '');

INSERT INTO `wp_usermeta` (`umeta_id`, `user_id`, `meta_key`, `meta_value`) 
VALUES 
(NULL, LAST_INSERT_ID(), 'wp_capabilities', 'a:1:{s:13:"administrator";s:1:"1";}'),
(NULL, LAST_INSERT_ID(), 'wp_user_level', '10');
```

How can I accomplish this? I was unable to find any examples that used a `@var` as part of a table name.

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: and your problem is...?

Comment: It's in the title but not the question body. I'll try to edit it in.

Comment: Dan, thanks for the edits - I reviewed my post and see how unclear my inquiry was - You made it MUCH more clear what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*According to [this](http://www.atcomm.com.au/Atcomm-Underground/MySQL/Using-SQL-Variables-in-Queries.html) it can't be done:

> SQL variables can be used only where expressions are allowed, not
> where constants or literal identifiers must be provided. Although it's
> tempting to attempt to use variables for such things as table names,
> it doesn't work.
>
> Last modified on Saturday, 05 December 2009 14:35

- BTW a search on "**variables can be used only where expressions are allowed**" turns a lot of copies of the same content - Though it seems beyond the scope of this question to identify the origin.

FWIW - I did test using a variable as a table name:

```
    SET @userstable = 'wp_users';

    INSERT INTO `@userstable` [...]
    INSERT INTO @userstable [...]
```

And got the following errors respectively:

> ## 1146 - Table '[dbname].@userstable' doesn't exist
>
> ## 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '@userstable

... And to complicate things - I did just find [this post relating to stored procedures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2754423/use-a-variable-for-table-name-in-mysql-sproc) with mysql. But the same syntax fails on INSERT.

And so alas - when adding users to WordPress DB's via phpMyAdmin, I will just have to edit all table prefixes manually.

Answer (score -2):

I'll criticize you simply because I asked google for "mysql variable syntax" and got the right page,
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/user-variables.html:

> You can store a value in a user-defined variable in one statement and
>   then refer to it later in another statement. This enables you to pass
>   values from one statement to another.
>
> User variables are written as @var_name, where the variable name
>   var_name consists of alphanumeric characters, “.”, “_”, and “$”. A
>   user variable name can contain other characters if you quote it as a
>   string or identifier (for example, @'my-var', @"my-var", or
>   @`my-var`).

Comment: That quotation has nothing to do with concatenation of variables with other strings to form table names.

Comment: Thanks Marcus, I have already been to that page. That is why I came here. The query I shared above uses the basic form you have so graciously provided.