# Passing in table for a procedure

Tags: mysql

How can someone pass in a table into a procedure and then output the first names inside the table?

Example:

```
myTable
firstName | lastName

John, Smith
Joe, Smith
Stan, Smith
```

And then only John, Joe and Stan pops up? I'm trying to make something similar for my personal website.

Here is what I have for MySQL:

```
 CREATE PROCEDURE 'test'.'returnFirstName' ()
```

Comment: Why do you have so many (enough) tables with the same structure to even warrant such a proc?

Comment: CREATE PROCEDURE `test`.`returnFirstName` (testTable)
SELECT testTable.firstName

Comment: Well, it's also for personal practice, too. I just want to know how to do it.

Comment: You'll need to construct the query as a string in the proc, and then PREPARE and EXECUTE that string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `test`.`returnFirstName` ()
BEGIN
  SELECT firstName 
  FROM myTable
END
```

To pass a parameter look at this: [use a variable for table name in mysql sproc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2754423/use-a-variable-for-table-name-in-mysql-sproc)

Execution SQL:

```
SELECT test.returnFirstName();
```

Comment: Is there anyway to pass the table into the parameters though? Or is this the only way to do it?

Comment: Yes, of course you can declare a parameter which contains this. But why do you want to do this?

Comment: Just so I know how to. :/